# SQL How to modify this table

Tags: sql

How to get this table in sql:

```
id   cunsumption_bhd cunsumption_metha 
id1  21.0            10.2
```

from this table:

```
id   type   cunsumption
id1  bhd    21.0
id1  metha  10.2
```

Comment: One option is to Pivot. Implementation depends on dbms used.

Answer (score 1):

Use a self join with a filter on the type for both "instances" of the table.

```
select t1.id, 
       t1.consumption as consumption_bhd, 
       t2.consumption as consumption_metha
from the_table t1
  join the_table t2 on t1.id = t2.id and t2.type = 'metha'
where t1.type = 'bhd'
  and t1.id = 'id1';
```

Answer (score 1):

One method is conditional aggregation:

```
select max(case when type = 'bhd' then consumption end) as consumption_bhd,
       max(case when type = 'metha' then consumption end) as consumption_metha
from t;
```