# How to get this table transformation?

Tags: sql, postgresql

[image: table transformation left to right]Hello I wanted to ask, if its possible to transform a table with a PostgreSQL command/code in the way described in my image (Left table should turn to right table). This is only an example and the table is in fact much bigger. I am not sure how to do it and got the advice of applying subselects and dynamical SQL programming, however I just cant find a solution.

This [SQL How to modify this table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56775320/sql-how-to-modify-this-table) is a similiar posed problem, however I just dont see how one can apply this dynamically?

Thanks for helping!

Tutorials, SQL programming, nothing really helped me get to find a solution to my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do a pivot in postgres is with case expressions.

```
SELECT idnumber,
       sum(CASE WHEN year = 1961 THEN hours ELSE NULL END) AS "year_1961",
       sum(CASE WHEN year = 1962 THEN hours ELSE NULL END) AS "year_1962",
       sum(CASE WHEN year = 1998 THEN hours ELSE NULL END) AS "year_1998"
FROM table
GROUP BY idnumber;
```

Some databases have a function that is supposed to allow you to do this more dynamically, so you can try to google PIVOT or CROSSTAB, but those usually are equally as annoying.

Unfortunately, **what we want, doesn't exist**.

Most people want the function to:  "make a new column for every possible value, without me having to type it."

Why it's not possible, I'm not exactly sure. But I do know that SQL is a declarative language, and we generally are defining how the result *is supposed to look*, instead of telling the system *what to do*.

I can offer a tip to write tedious SQL faster, but it will still require you to at least type out the values in a single list.

You can write a template like this,

```
SELECT idnumber, 
{%- for yr in years %}
sum(CASE WHEN year = {{yr}} THEN hours ELSE NULL END) AS year_{{yr}}{{',' if not loop.last}}
{%- endfor %}
FROM table
GROUP BY idnumber
```

And then pass it the list of years that you want like this:

```
years: ['1961','1962','1963','1964']
```

And the output will be the longer SQL:

```
SELECT idnumber,
sum(CASE WHEN year = 1961 THEN hours ELSE NULL END) AS year_1961,
sum(CASE WHEN year = 1962 THEN hours ELSE NULL END) AS year_1962,
sum(CASE WHEN year = 1963 THEN hours ELSE NULL END) AS year_1963,
sum(CASE WHEN year = 1964 THEN hours ELSE NULL END) AS year_1964
FROM table
GROUP BY idnumber
```

You can try that out [here](http://jinja.quantprogramming.com/).

Comment: Admittedly, one of the downsides of postgres is not having a Pivot function. Such a powerful platform, yet dont have a such a fundamental feature available. Maybe there is a reason for that, too.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! However my main problem is exactly the part on how to use this dynamically as I havent found anything to that which solves my problem.

Comment: You haven't found it, because it doesn't exist, @Jan.  The only way to do it dynamically involves doing stuff outside of SQL

Comment: @ZiyaMertKarakas don't be jealous of other systems w/ a PIVOT function, it's not as fun as you might think. BigQuery, Snowflake, they all do them differently and they're NOT easy to use. In fact they still require you to list out each unique value, so its not really dynamic anyways. Recently I have started ignoring them and using the "standard" method instead.

Comment: @Josh, yes I feel you, maybe its better to leave it unimplemented and let the user do the fine-tuning. Jan, SQL is set-based, and a static language, so dynamic parameterization is not possible as Josh has said